# How do I get the document ID from firebase observable collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Now that firebase queries have changed I'm unable to get the document ID.  I can retrieve the documents but not the ID associated with them.

Here's the actual service:

```js
  getdata(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    const iQuery: Query<DocumentData> = query(
      collection(this.firestore, 'collection'),
      where('userInfo.userId', '==', uid));

    return collectionData(iQuery);
  }
```

Calling the service in the class:

```js
  itineraryQuery(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.itineraryService.getItineraries(uid)
  }
```

and finally calling the class method onInit()

```js
    this.itineraryQuery(this.userInfo.uid).forEach(
      snap => {
        this.myItineraries = snap
      });
```

Typically what'd usually do is snap.data() or snap.id.  Neither of those exist on snap.  Using snap gives me all of the documents but when I console log them there's no ID.  All of the StackOverflow posts show the same thing...someone using snap.data() or snap.id, but for some reason that doesn't exist for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which package are you using? Could you please include your package.json to further reproduce your issue.

Comment: "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",